# Editing a GUI in Flash CC 2015

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm using Flash CC 2015. I am working on a project (I am the graphic designer) I have been given a flash file that is all .as files and was asked to change the GUI. I cannot for the life of me find a way to edit it visually.

Is there no way to do this after the programmers have finished? If there is could you point me in the right direction or tell me how to edit it?

Really lost at this point since there are no actions in their fla file just a bunch of class files.

Comment: If you're using FlashDevelop, then no GUI designer is available. If you're using Flash CS, there is a GUI designer (which is primary in that environment) that creates "hidden" AS3 code to initialize and place objects pre-placed in GUI.

Comment: I'm using Flash CC 2015.

Comment: is there anything in the library? (open the library widnow) its possible all the graphics are generated by code, in which case it may not be the job of a designer to change them

Comment: In the .fla file there's nothing in the library. If I go to the gui.as I can see where things are being called to, but cannot figure out how to edit where they are. (Since I'm just a graphic designer I know a bit of code, but not much.) I can see how they are assembled. I've been given the illustrator files for the gui, but they want me to change it around and I have no clue if I can do this to the .as files.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to edit it, because it only exists when the code is being executed.

Think about the code as a recipe for a meal. There's no way to get to the meal without following the recipe. "Following the recipe" means executing the code.

I don't see how this is the job of a designer either. A designer has nothing to do with the underlying implementation. A designer isn't given code to modify, a programmer is.

> asked to change the GUI

A polite decline is in order. Maybe they thought you could do this. If they couldn't do it themselves, they probably have no clue either. It is not necessarily bad intent to ask you. It is a matter of politeness to be honest and to clarify that you cannot do this. This is the best solution. 
If you agree to do this on the other hand, you will run into problems or possibly even break something. Which is unlikely the intent of those asking your for help.

Comment: They probably asked because I've edited their flash files before, but the actionscript was on the timeline or the buttons were right in front of me. With this the most I can do is edit their buttons through illustrator. But I guess everyone is right. I'm going to have to ask them to ask their programmers to either make a gui I can see and let them set it up based on the edits or something.